# How to get the selected value in dropdownlist when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to get the selected value in dropdownlist when submit button is clicked?
Selected value should display in console. 
I am getting the selected value, but I am getting in array with 3 values.

```
<div class="form-group">
                                     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>
                                     <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
                                            <select name="drop"  onchange="a()">
                                                    <option ></option>
                                                    <option>Bangalore</option>
                                                    <option >HYD</option>
                                                    <option >RJY</option>
                                                  </select>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()" value="Submit">
```

This the Js Code:

```
var user = {
    name : "",
    fname : "",
    posaddress :"",
    peraddress : "",
    gender : "",
    city :"",

};

var sdvalues = [];
function getData(){
    user.name = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    user.fname = document.getElementById("fName").value;
    user.posaddress = document.getElementById("addressLine1").value;
    user.peraddress = document.getElementById("addressLine2").value;
    user.state = document.getElementById("state").value;

   var gen = document.getElementsByName("gender");
   for(i=0; i<gen.length; i++) {
       if(gen[i].checked){
         user.gender = gen[i].value;
       }

   }
  console.log(user);
       }

       function a(){
           var ddown = document.getElementsByName("drop");
           for(i=0; i<ddown.length; i++){
            sdvalues.push(ddown[i].options[ddown[i].selectedIndex].value);{
                user.city = sdvalues;

               }

           }

    }
```

I need to get the one selected value from dropdownlist

Comment: You say you want to get selected value when button is pressed, but in your code you do some action when selected value is changed. So when do you want to obtain selected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  function a(){
     var e = document.getElementsByName("drop")[0];
     var selected= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     console.log(selected);
    }
```

```html
     <select name="drop"  onchange="a()">
        <option ></option>
         <option>Bangalore</option>
         <option >HYD</option>
         <option >RJY</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: I don't want to use selected in html, dynamically i need get the value when I select the value from drop down

Comment: Whenever you will select the option form <select> tag it will add the selected tag in it check it. try to run above code

Comment: document.getElementsByName("drop")[0] , In this what is the use of  this "[0]", Please  Can you explain me ??

Comment: The getElementsByName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document. It will return you nodelist an array starting with index 0.

Answer (score 0):

If the html is yours to modify, you could change "drop" from a name to an id, so that you can get the whole selection as a single element, whose value will be the selected string.

```js
function a(){
var dDown=document.getElementById("drop");//by id gives just one element, the whole thing
console.log(dDown.value);//and its value is what you want
}
```

```html
<select id="drop" name="drop" onchange="a()">
                                                    <option ></option>
                                                    <option>Bangalore</option>
                                                    <option >HYD</option>
                                                    <option >RJY</option>
                                                  </select>
```